# FormArray in Angular TypeError value.forEach

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

i have my FormService

```
    title: this.fb.group({
    titleList: this.fb.array([]),
    name: ['', [Validators.requiredValidator()]]
    }),
```

i add dynamic in my list with button new names

my Testing Class code

```
  const mock = { title: {
  titleList: new FormArray([]),
  name: 'Movie one',
  }}

  formService.get().setValue(mock);
```

my mock have another form elements - i cut it for this part
i get the error: **Failed: value.forEach is not a function, TypeError: value.forEach is not a function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 const mock = { title: {
  titleList: [],
  name: 'Movie one',
  }}

  formService.get().setValue(mock);
```

You set a value, you don't create a new form.